# Shadowbox - Auto close upon php form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to get shadowbox to close once form is submitted. currently my php is set to refresh the survey question. Now that i am using shadowbox to load the survey on page load i want it to disappear once the submit button is pressed.

Site link: [Survey site.](http://www.wellcontrol.com/survey-page.html)

My php code is:

```
<?php
$to = "milam.matthew@gmail.com";
$subject = 'Survey Results'; 
$group1 = $_POST["group1"];
$headers  = "From: $name <$email>\n";  
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$mes .= 'Training Method Preferred: '.$group1;  
{
    mail($to, $subject, $mes, $headers);
}
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

I'm not sure if this is something I should write in the php code or in the shadowbox.js. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend to you, create a session or cookie var when an user visit your website, soo you can create a question 
if($_SESSION['usr'] == 1)
 //ShADOWBOX IS NOT VISIBLE
If you want hidden the shadowbox when the user click on submit, that's easy with jquery, but your submit, send the form, and refresh the page, and therefore, would not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Could try this -

Check if group1 has been submitted and add a class to the shadowbox.

Then only open shadowbox if has class of open.

PHP

```
<?php    
    $shadowboxClass = '';

    if (!isset($_POST["group1"])) {
        $shadowboxClass = '.open';
    }
?>

<div id="sb-container" class="<?php echo $shadowboxClass; ?>">
```

jQuery

```
window.onload = function() {

    if($("#sb-container").hasClass('open')){

        // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
        Shadowbox.open({
            content:    '<div id="welcome-msg">Welcome to my website!</div>',
            player:     "html",
            title:      "Welcome",
            height:     350,
            width:      350
        });
    }
};
```

Then as Netzach suggested you should set a session variable, but then just make that the if statement.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["group1"]) && !empty($_POST["group1"])) {
        $to = "milam.matthew@gmail.com";
        $subject = 'Survey Results'; 
        $group1 = $_POST["group1"];
        $headers  = "From: $name <$email>\n";  
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        $mes .= 'Training Method Preferred: '.$group1;  
        {
            mail($to, $subject, $mes, $headers);
        }

        $_SESSION['submitedSurvey'] = 1;

        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    $shadowboxClass = '';

    if ($_SESSION['submitedSurvey'] != 1) {
        $shadowboxClass = '.open';
    }

?>

<div id="sb-container" class="<?php echo $shadowboxClass; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

then ... I recommend to you, use $_SESSION var when received the form.

For example:
your form: ShadowBox

```
<form id="form" action="process.php">
//YOUR RADIOBUTTONS OR CHeCKBOX 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn_submit">
</form>
```

process.php

```
<? 
$_POST['myCheckbox'];
$_SESSION['user'] = 1;

//.... etc etc your source...
?>
```

Now, your page again

```
<? if($_SESSION['user'] != 1){//the user already filled in the form 
   //YOUR SHADOWBOX CODE
}?>
```

With Jquery is very easy hide the box when you click on submit

```
<script>
$('#btn_submit').click(function(){
  $('#theiddivoryourshadowbox').hide();
});
</script>
```

Then, if you do not want refresh the page, I recommend to you use a link and not a button, then you can use ajax for send the form, and immediately after of click on the link, you hide the div box with hide(); jquery function. 
If you want be helped with this code, please just order it!